# Unexpected behavior with NSMutableOrderedSet

Tags: objective-c, nsset

Using an NSMutableOrderedSet, I'm getting unexpected behavior.

I set an object at index 0. In the next call, I read out the object at index 0. How is it that the pointer I get back is not the same as the one I just inserted?

```
- (void)setRecentObject:(SomeObject *)recentObject
{
    // self.activeQueue is a viable instance of NSMutableOrderedSet

    [[self activeTileQueue] insertObject:recentObject atIndex:0];
    SomeObject *whatIJustInserted = [[self activeTileQueue] objectAtIndex:0];

    DebugLog(@"set url at zero: %@, and read back url at zero: %@",[recentObject someDescription], [whatIJustInserted someDescription]);

}
```

To my thinking, at the end of this method, recentObject should == whatIJustInsereted -- and yet both in my logging statement and when I evaluate the pointers after setting a breakpoint, the objects are different instances of SomeObject. Is there something I don't understand about NSMutableOrderedSet?

Comment: It seems that `insertObject:atIndex` causes the NSMutableOrderedSet to rearrange the objects internally. If you call `addObject`, the `objectAtIndex:index` will return the same address.

Comment: @BorisProhaska It should rearrange the objects and shift the other objects indices by +1 -- but still, if I set an object at zero and then read the object at zero, it should be the same. If I add the object, it will append it to the set (as I understand it), such that then retrieving the object at index zero *would* be different...

Comment: I can't reproduce with `[NSMutableArray new]` as `recentObject`. Do you still get the error if you create a simple test case like that? If not, the error is not in this code.

Comment: @Chuck I don't get the behavior with an array, but I am trying to ensure an unique set of objects. I now believe the this is part of the issue -- when I'm calling this method, recentTile is already a member of activeTileQueue. My expectation was that if the object was already a member, it would be repositioned to occupy index 0. It appears that the object simply isn't added if the set already contains it.

Comment: @isaac: Yes, that's correct. Trying to add an object to an NSMutableOrderedSet has no effect if the object is already in the set. (Incidentally, I meant using an NSMutableArray in place of SomeObject, not in place of the set. I obviously don't have access to your SomeObject class, so I just used NSMutableArray instead for testing.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this did not behave as expected is because the receiver activeTileQueue (the NSMutableOrderedSet instance) already contained the member.

While I specifically sought the use of a set versus an array because I didn't want duplicates of any objects inserted, my assumption about how the insertion would work in this case was incorrect. I assumed that if the set already contained the member I was attempting to insert, that rather than be re-insereted, the member would be repositioned to the index passed in -insertObjectAtIndex. This was incorrect.

If the receiver already contains the member, it is not re-inserted or re-ordered. In short, nothing happens. To obtain the originally desired behavior, I would have to either remove the original member and re-insert it, or use another method on NSMutableOrdered set to reposition/exchange the index within the set, eg:

```
NSIndexSet *replacementSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[[self activeTileQueue] indexOfObject:recentObject]];
[[self activeTileQueue] moveObjectsAtIndexes:replacementSet toIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks for investigating the behavior of -insertObject:atIndex: when the object is already in the set - the docs are silent on this.